# How to prevent randomly generated images from overlapping using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to spawn randomly generated targets on the screen using a function to copy an invisible image of the target to be spawned at a random place within the screen using window object properties. 
For this to happen I think the image have to have position set to absolute, but then several images may be spawned in a way that they will overlap, how can I prevent this from happening?

**The div element where I copy my first image and also store the other copies.**

```
<div id="targetsDiv">
    <img src="target2.png" alt="target_shot" class="target" />      
</div>
```

**Inside the script:**

```
var x_pixels = window.innerWidth - 180;
var y_pixels = window.innerHeight - 180;
var x_midScreen = window.innerWidth / 2;
var y_midScreen = window.innerHeight / 2;

var xRandom = Math.floor(Math.random()*x_pixels) +1;
var yRandom = Math.floor(Math.random()*y_pixels) +1;

var targetCollection = document.getElementById("targetsDiv");
var targetCopy = targetCollection.innerHTML
var targetList = document.getElementsByClassName("target");
targetList[0].style.display = "none";
var targetNr = 1;

var numberOfSpawns = 3;

function spawnTargets () {
    while (targetNr <= numberOfSpawns) {
        if ((xRandom < x_midScreen - 126 || xRandom > x_midScreen + 26) || (yRandom < y_midScreen - 126 || yRandom > y_midScreen + 26)) {
            targetCollection.innerHTML += targetCopy;
            targetList[targetNr].style.left = xRandom + "px";
            targetList[targetNr].style.top = yRandom + "px";
            targetNr++;
        } 
            xRandom = Math.floor(Math.random()*x_pixels) +1;
            yRandom = Math.floor(Math.random()*y_pixels) +1;
    }
}
```

PS: I appreciate all help, tips and tweaks that you guys provide:) Thanks for helping

Comment: Use a check like: `function genNewTarget(){/*Target gen code*/ for(var i=0; i<targets.length;i++){if(newTarget.x+newTarget.width>targets[i].x&&newTarget.x<targets[i].x+targets[i].width&&newTarget.y+newTarget.height>targets[i].y&&newTarget.y<targets[i].y+targets[i].height){genNewTarget();}else{return newTarget;}}}`

Comment: Note: That's just pseudo-code, it doesn't use real variable/function names.

Comment: What is the significance of the numbers 450, 300, ...etc? You seem to have other rules as to where the images can appear or not. Can you explain?

Comment: Yeah, I have a button in the middle of the screen. And images will not appear 300px on the horizontal side of the button or 200px on the vertical side (the image is 150px). There's probably a better way of doing it, but I'm fairly new to JavaScript and this was the best I could think of

Comment: On my laptop's screen resolution no image would fit under those conditions. you are excluding 750 pixels from the x coordinate, and 550 from the y coordinate, that is quite a lot and takes most of my screen size. How do you plan your application will run on devices with smaller resolutions or with browsers not maximised?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the if condition. Now only a 50px box in the very center will be free from images. I made it spawn on a mouseover function, and this is how it would looke like on a small window (window size down right) -> [link](https://gyazo.com/e1b2263b915cf8a2d7279711048ace05) Also I didn't have my mind set on other people's screen size as I just learned "document.getElement..." at school and tried to make something out of it.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see you had written another answer, I looked over it and replied just now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The area you want to exclude in the centre of the screen is rather large, and on my little laptop, there isn't even any room to still show the random positioned images.

But anyway, this piece of code should do the job -- I added some infinite loop protection which on my PC was a life-saver:

#### HTML (added `style` attribute)

```
<div id="targetsDiv">
    <img src="target2.png" alt="target_shot" class="target" 
        style="visibility:hidden"/>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var targetCollection = document.getElementById("targetsDiv");
    var template = document.getElementsByClassName("target")[0];

    var targetWidth = template.offsetWidth;
    var targetHeight = template.offsetHeight;
    var x_pixels = window.innerWidth - targetWidth;
    var y_pixels = window.innerHeight - targetHeight;
    var x_midScreen = window.innerWidth / 2;
    var y_midScreen = window.innerHeight / 2;
    function spawnTargets (numberOfSpawns) {
        var targets = [];
        var count = 0; // infinite recursion protection
        for (var i = 0; i < numberOfSpawns; i++) {
            do {
                do {
                    var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*x_pixels);
                    var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*y_pixels);
                    if (count++ > 200) {
                        console.log('give up');
                        return;
                    }
                } while ((x >= x_midScreen-450 && x <= x_midScreen+300) && (y >= y_midScreen-350 || y <= y_midScreen+200));

                for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                    if (x >= targets[j].x - targetWidth && x <= targets[j].x + targetWidth && 
                        y >= targets[j].y - targetHeight && y <= targets[j].y + targetHeight) break; // not ok!
                }
            } while (j < i);
            targets.push({x, y});

            img = document.createElement('img');
            img.src = template.src;
            img.setAttribute('width', targetWidth + 'px');
            img.setAttribute('height', targetHeight + 'px');
            img.className = template.className;
            targetCollection.appendChild(img);
            img.style.left = x + "px";
            img.style.top = y + "px";
        }
    }
    spawnTargets(3);
});
```

Comment: Wow thanks! This was really helpful, I saw feathercrowns answer about the collision check, but I didn't know how to integrate it into my code as I've not learned much Javascript yet for example (do, offset, appendChild, createElement, addEventListener, .push,  and break;) but I will be reading up on all of these tomorrow! Thanks for learning me something

Comment: You're welcome. The `appendChild`, `createElement` stuff replaces what you did with `innerHTML`: it is considered better practice to do it this way. `push` is the way to add elements to an array. That array records the previous positions, and so can then be used to compare the newly generated position against.